# Text Validation with ListView

Tags: vb.net, listview

I'm currently trying to figure out how to validate my text boxes in regards to List View inserting. The text boxes are declared as strings below.

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Col1 As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim Col2 As String = TextBox2.Text
        Dim col3 As String = TextBox3.Text
        Dim col4 As String = RichTextBox2.Text
        Dim col5 As String = DateTimePicker1.Text
        Dim col6 As String = DateTimePicker2.Text
        Dim col7 As String = RichTextBox2.Text
        If Col1 Or Col2 Or col3 Or col4 Or col5 Or col6 Or col7 = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill in any missing field. Remember and select a date in both date fields!")
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
            lvi.Text = Col1 'Adds to First column
            lvi.SubItems.Add(Col2)
            lvi.SubItems.Add(col3)
            lvi.SubItems.Add(col4)
            lvi.SubItems.Add(col5)
            lvi.SubItems.Add(col6)
            lvi.SubItems.Add(col7) 'Adds to Second column
            ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
        End If
    End Sub
```

It just takes data from the strings(textboxes) and puts them into order of the list view table. I depends on every text box having some sort of data in it. if there is one field missing, each column in the table moves to left if you get me? Is there a possible way to validate then make a condition. i tried to do one but i don't have an overly extensive knowledge in VB so had a feeling it wouldn't work.

Comment: you should (also) break that into 2 methods: one to perform data validation, one to add to the LV. ` if there is one field missing, each column in the table moves to left` you probably do not want to do that or your code wont know what is in each column for any given row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's *a lot* of issues with your code. First thing you should do is to set the [Option Strict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) compiler option to **`On`**. (Read the section *"To set Option Strict in the IDE")*

VS will then highlight `Col1` and `Col2` with the following error message:

> *Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Long'*

At this point you should head over to MSDN and look at the documentation for the [Or Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06s37a7f.aspx).

> *<Boolean>* result = *<Boolean>* expression1  Or *<Boolean>* expression2

As you can see, both the LHS and RHS argument needs to be a boolean value.

```
Dim result As Boolean = (Col1 = "") Or (Col2 = "")
```

So you need to repeat this for each and every expression.

```
If Col1 = "" Or Col2 = "" Or col3 = "" Or col4 = "" Or col5 = "" Or col6 = "" Or col7 = "" Then
```

Another option is to store the controls in an array and use the [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method.

```
Dim controls As Control() = {
    TextBox1,
    TextBox2,
    TextBox3,
    RichTextBox2,
    DateTimePicker1,
    DateTimePicker2,
    RichTextBox2
}

If (controls.Any(Function(c As Control) c.Text = "")) Then
    'Display error message
```

Also, note that the common way to [validate user input in winforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is to handle the [Validating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Validated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validated(v=vs.110).aspx) events.

Comment: Thanks very much Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå. Worked a treat!